# how to create a clean oracle database without excess tables in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

why am i seeing these , ready made tables inside my newly created connection in my oracle 11g express, via oracle sql developer?,
what i did was, I just created a new connection, with username as system, and password as sasori....then when i clicked the "tables",
i saw alot of tables in it which i didn't created my self

```
AQ$_DEF$_AQERROR_F
AQ$_INTERNET_AGENTS
AQ$_INTERNET_AGENT_PRIVS
AQ$_QUEUE_TABLES
DEF$_DESTINATION
DEF$_PROPAGATOR
DEF$_PUSHED_TRANSACTIONS
LOGMNRC_DBNAME_UID_MAP
LOGMNRC_GSBA
```

and etc.etc...etc....
how can i create a new connection w/o those tables automatically created

Comment: A system user will see system tables...

Comment: then how create a connection with my own user, hence i need a new user.am using an 11g xe edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new database comes with a couple of standard users. This allows you to manage the database. One of the tasks is to create your own users.

First you create a connection as user system.

When you are connected as system, you can now create a new user.

Make a new connection using this new users credentials.

Comment: thanks for the answer man, i also found the ,how to create a user in this link http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=257